# Can not get location updates in background

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am trying to develop an app in which I am getting users location updates and when user reaches at some location I am performing some actions. For getting location updates I am using following code.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    1000,1f,locationListener);
```

And I am trying to catch location changes in locationlistener's overrided method as follow:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.e("JK-->>","location updated by gpsping service-->> "+location.getLatitude()+
                            " "+location.getLongitude());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location changed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

When I tried it on emulator it works fine in foreground and background and also after removing app from recent apps list but problem is that when I try it on real device it's showing toast when my app is open in foreground or background but when I remove my app from recent app it's not showing toast.
When I open map from any application (e.g. in googlemap, in my app or in any other app) it's showing toast even if my app is not in recent app list.
Hence I can say that my service is running even if my app is killed from recent app but locationmanager can't get location updates.

I have tried to find out solution and I found suggestion to use FusedLocationProviderClient. I have also tried this but it also doesn't work. So, if anyone have solution then please suggest.

**Using FusedLocationProviderClient**

```
locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                    .setInterval(1000)
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setFastestInterval(1000);

            LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    Log.e("JK-->>","location updated by gpsping service-->> "+locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+
                            " "+locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location changed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the location code in sticky service, then start this service as a `foreground`.
take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) for more information